# Auth::logout() gives error if used in login page(without login). Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logout, laravel-5.5

I'm working with laravel 5.5. I just have little problem about `Auth::logout()` function. This function works fine but if I use this route path (write manually) in login page (unlogged user) this will give me error like this. What do I have to do for prevent this error message?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `logout` route, is by default a POST route, trying to reach it via typing in an address would cause a GET request which would be `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. (Assuming you registered the routes via `Route::auth()`)

Comment: Yeah, thanks man :) I don't consider method type. )))) Yeah, I used `make:auth` and `Auth:routes()`

Comment: That means i have to write GET request path manually for `logout` ? for if anyone write logout and maybe this error shows up. ?

Comment: there is only a POST route setup for logout, so you would need to use a form and submit to that URL to actually logout. (This stops someone from sending you a link that could log you out of your site). If you want to have `logout` as a GET route, be able to type logout or have a regular link to it, you can add a GET route with the same URI pointing to the same controller method

Comment: I just want to prevent error message for GET request. I'll skim again my code. Because all layout is laravel core auth pages :) Thanks for replying :)

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1125    that is the `logout` route that is registered for you ... add another one just like this, but `get` instead of `post`

Comment: also remember when `debug` ends up being set to `false`, that error wont be shown ... you can also catch these types of Exceptions in the handler and decide what you would like to do with them, perhaps redirect or show some type of 'hey we can't find what you are looking for' type page

Comment: @rufatZZ you dont need to touch anything there ... just add another route to your `web.php` routes file

Comment: Oh man, I think i have to add one line of route here )) Okay , I try my best for learn and good practise :)